# In Addition Algorithm binary what is point of multiplying carry with 2?

Tags: algorithm, binary, addition, discrete-mathematics

*To add a and b, first add their rightmost bits. This gives
a0 + b0 = c0 ⋅ 2 + s0,
 where s0 is the rightmost bit in the binary expansion of a + b and c0 is the carry, which is either
0 or 1.
Then add the next pair of bits and the carry, a1 +b1 +c0 =c1 ⋅2+s1,*

**since we just add the carry C0 with the next operation without multiplying by 2 ???? why? or i am wrong here?**

**thanks in advance**

Comment: In binary, the next digit is already twice the previous digit so no need to multiply by 2

Comment: Here `c1 ⋅2+s1` means "the 2-bit number written as the bit c1 followed by the bit s1", just like in decimal, `a*10 + b` means "the 2-digit number written as the digit a followed by the digit b". For instance, the decimal number 63 can be written as `6*10+3`. In the addition algorithm, the left-bit or left-digit is going to be the carry.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this with a simple example.
We are adding `3(a) + 5(b)` or `11 + 101`. Following the described algorithm above we get.

To add `11(a)` and `101(b)`, first add their rightmost bits. `1(a0) + 1(b0)`. This gives `1(a0) + 1(b0) = 1(c0) * 2 + 0(s0)`.

Multiplying by 2 here in binary is a bitshift, you are moving that 1 to the next binary place in the number so `1*2+0 = 10` which is the result of `1+1`.

So following the next pair of bits `1(a1) + 0(b1) + 1(c0) = 1(c1)*2+0(s1)`.

This may seem counterintuitive, but the c0 digit originally belongs to the first binary place `(0th index)`, by multiplying it by 2 we ensure we can add it with the bits on the second binary place `(1st index)`.

The addition on   `a1 +b1 +c0 =c1 ⋅2+s1` is not possible without this `2*` multiplication on `c0` for we would be adding otherwise  `10(a1) + 00(b1) + 01(c0)` which is not the desired result for the second binary place